# How to Use Collapsing ToolBar with a ListView instead of a Recycler View

Tags: android, listview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Does anyone know how to implement the Collapsing Toolbar using A listview instead of a recycler view?

Comment: To make collapsing `Toolbar` you need to use `CoordinatorLayout`. And it works only with `ScrollingView` and `NestedScrollingChild` interfaces. `RecyclerView` implements it. `ListView` not.

Comment: Just wondering: Could you write a CustomView that extends ListView and implements ScrollingView and NestedScrollingChild and then use it in CollapsingToolbar?

Comment: Okay Thanks @Foxinsocks I guess I'll have to rearrange a bunch of my ListView Code to Recycler Views.

Comment: @BenjaminScharbau Let me Try it as a demo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make it woks you should to:

1. Implement NestedScrollingChild in your custom ListView implementation.
2. Add field `private final NestedScrollingChildHelper mScrollingChildHelper;` and init it in constructors
3. Delegate to it methods from  NestedScrollingChild
4. Invoke `setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);` after `mScrollingChildHelper` initialization

Here is my list view implementation for example:

```
public class NestedScrollingListView extends ListView implements NestedScrollingChild {

    private final NestedScrollingChildHelper mScrollingChildHelper;

    public NestedScrollingListView(Context context) {
       super(context);
       mScrollingChildHelper = new NestedScrollingChildHelper(this);
       setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
    }

    public NestedScrollingListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
       mScrollingChildHelper = new NestedScrollingChildHelper(this);
       setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void setNestedScrollingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
       mScrollingChildHelper.setNestedScrollingEnabled(enabled);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNestedScrollingEnabled() {
       return mScrollingChildHelper.isNestedScrollingEnabled();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean startNestedScroll(int axes) {
       return mScrollingChildHelper.startNestedScroll(axes);
    }

    @Override
    public void stopNestedScroll() {
        mScrollingChildHelper.stopNestedScroll();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNestedScrollingParent() {
        return mScrollingChildHelper.hasNestedScrollingParent();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchNestedScroll(int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed,
                                    int dyUnconsumed, int[] offsetInWindow) {
        return mScrollingChildHelper.dispatchNestedScroll(dxConsumed, dyConsumed,
            dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed, offsetInWindow);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchNestedPreScroll(int dx, int dy, int[] consumed, int[] offsetInWindow) {
        return mScrollingChildHelper.dispatchNestedPreScroll(dx, dy, consumed, offsetInWindow);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchNestedFling(float velocityX, float velocityY, boolean consumed) {
        return mScrollingChildHelper.dispatchNestedFling(velocityX, velocityY, consumed);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchNestedPreFling(float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        return mScrollingChildHelper.dispatchNestedPreFling(velocityX, velocityY);
    }
}
```

Comment: why can't we wrap the listview in a nestedscrollview ? . NestedScrollView also implements nestedscrollingchild doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Only add this code to your project. 
It only work in Lollipop devices and later.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    listView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
    listView.startNestedScroll(View.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make nested scrolling work on pre-Lollipop devices, which you probably do, you have to use corresponding utility classes from the Support library. First you have to replace you ScrollView with NestedScrollView. The latter implements both NestedScrollingParent and NestedScrollingChild so it can be used as a parent or a child scroll container.

But ListView doesn't support nested scrolling, therefore you need to subclass it and implement NestedScrollingChild. Fortunately, the Support library provides NestedScrollingChildHelper class, so you just have to create an instance of this class and call its methods from the corresponding methods of your view class.